# symfony 4 create testing DB

Tags: symfony4

I have `.env` and `.env.test` files with different `APP_ENV` and `DATABASE_URL` values.

In `.env` I have `DATABASE_URL=pgsql://postgres:asdfasdf@db:5432/real_db` and in `.env.test` I have `DATABASE_URL=pgsql://postgres:asdfasdf@db:5432/test_db`

But when I run command `bin/console doctrine:database:create --if-not-exists --env=test` I can see message **Database "real_db" for connection named default already exists. Skipped**

So looks like for some reason Symfony cli can't recognize env correctly.

Also, I having a pretty similar issue when running `bin/console doctrine:schema:update --end=dev`. When I run it I see warning message **[CAUTION] This operation should not be executed in a production environment!** and I need to use `--force` to update the schema.

How can I fix this, especially issue with no ability to create testing DB? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `.env` file only work on `dev` environment. So `.env.xxx` not related to any environment, you can't split `env` file like that but you need to manually `export` environment's variables for each environment. Read more from this link https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/environments.html and http://fabien.potencier.org/symfony4-best-practices.html

For testing variables can be defined in `phpunit.xml` -- See https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing/database.html#changing-database-settings-for-functional-tests

And for `[CAUTION] This operation should not be executed in a production environment!` is a good caution don't worry about it, using `--force` can prevent you from some mistake.